# I'm trying to copy information from 1 dataframe to another where df_1['date'] = df_2['date']. i'm stuck

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes.

Both df(s) have a date column.

I want to copy a column `['Volume']` from `df_2` to `df_1` where the `df_1['date'] = df_2['date']`.

I can loop through the 1st df, but after that, I'm lost...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1):

Use `df1.merge(df2[columns], how='inner', on='Date')`. For Example:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['Monday', 'Tuesday'], 'Random': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['Monday', 'Wednesday'], 'Volume': [3, 4]})

print(df1.merge(df2[['Date', 'Volume']], how='inner', on='Date'))
```

Output:

```
     Date  Random  Volume
0  Monday       1       3
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html